# Circuitpython and Japanese Scripts

Tags: python, cjk, adafruit-circuitpython

I work with Python a bit and Japanese language a lot.  I'm wanting to build a microcontroller based flashcard device for practice.  Currently I have a PyGamer that I've been playing with and I decided to try to try out a few things.

Very first thing `print("Hello, 日本語")` produces `Hello, 日本語` in the REPL, but `Hello, !` on the PyGamer screen.

Normally I would add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the head of the file to my Python scripts, but it makes no change in CircuitPython.  My searches have been fruitless, so I'm hoping someone here will have an idea.

Thanks
-nathan-

Comment: what font do you use ? Maybe this font doesn't have Japanese chars.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback furas; unfortunately that didn't help.

I was doing more research on the subject and came across this on the micropython site:  [Micropython Builtin Types](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/genrst/builtin_types.html?highlight=utf)

I tried `print(str('日本語'), encoding = 'utf 8')` but ended up getting the output `NotImplementedError: keyword argument(s) not yet implemented - use normal args instead`.  Tried this on circuitpython and micropython and got the same results.

Looks like I'm going to have to wait a bit longer.